# Iframe postback causing MVC method to reload everything

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe

Is it possible to catch a postback in MVC method? Because every time my iframe postbacks, it does all my codes in my MVC method, such as getting data from the database; this is expensive.

**in my html**

```
<IFrame name="iframeReport" src="~/MVCController/MyMethod?param1=value1&param2=value2"/>
```

**MVCController.cs**

```
public class MVCController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyMethod(string param1, string param2)
    {
        // some codes here getting data from database
        return View(new MyModel(data));
    }
}
```

is it possible to know if it is a postback? some thing like this:

```
public class MVCController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyMethod(string param1, string param2)
    {
        If(!isPostback)
        {
           // some codes here getting data from database
        }
        return View(new MyModel(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: MVC does not use postbacks; That is for webforms.

Comment: As DigitalD said, There is no postback in mvc 4. Use ajax.BeginForm and return PartialView().